# Safely clear JavaScript timeout

Tags: javascript, timer

I have created a JavaScript function that does the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    DoStuff;
    watch = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}
```

where

```
watch
```

is a global variable initially set to null.

Then, I have a second function, that can be called at any moment, of the form:

```
function mySecond() {
    DoStuff;
    clearTimeout(watch);
}
```

Now, it happens sometimes that, although the second function is called and the timeout is somehow cleared, the first function is called another time. I guess this is happening because when the second function is called, a request for the first function has already been sent, and thus the timer works another time, and keeps calling itself over and over... I would like to point out that this does not happen always, I guess it depends on a specific timing condition you can encounter.

How to safely remove ALL the possibilities that the first function is called again?

Comment: This sounds more like you need to clean up your design so you know exactly who is calling what and under what circumstances rather than hack your code to control something you don't really understand.  I'd suggest settings a breakpoint in `myFunction()` and see who exactly is calling it and messing you up and fix the caller.

Comment: The involved functions are the ones cited in my question. I perfectly understand my code, and no one else is interacting with them.

Comment: Then how is it that `myFunction()` is getting called when you don't want it to?  No code you have disclosed is calling it ever.  The operative code here is code that is calling `myFunction()`.  That is obviously what needs to be fixed.  Timing issues are fixed by clear and structured design with a full understanding of all possible calling sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with this code is `watch` holds the last timeout only. This should fix it

```
function myFunction() {
      DoStuff;
      if (watch) { clearTimeout(watch); }
      watch = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}
```